# Invalid copy source object key in aws-java-sdk

Tags: scala, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

I'm trying to copy Parquet files from one AWS S3 bucket to another via Scala code. I get an exception on the copy call. Here's a stack trace:

```
software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: Invalid copy source object key (Service: S3, Status Code: 400, Request ID: ZDSVGXX276C1F416)
```

I pass the valid path to the s3 bucket and a file name to the method call. So what could be the reason for this issue?

The code for copying files that causes an error:

```
 def copyObjects(fromBucket: String, objectKey: String, toBucket: String): CopyObjectResponse = {
    val copyRequest = CopyObjectRequest
      .builder()
      .copySource(fromBucket)
      .destinationBucket(toBucket)
      .destinationKey(objectKey)
      .build()

    val copyResponse = awsS3Client.copyObject(copyRequest)

    val contents = copyResponse.copyObjectResult.toString
    logger.info(s"Copy response contents ${contents}")
    logger.info(s"Found ${contents.length} elements in storage with path $fromBucket")
    copyResponse
  }
```

And the method call:

```
copyFiles("s3a://qa/snapshots/urls/date=20220822.parquet", "part-00192-4130220041757319704-c12af88d-c000.snappy.parquet", "s3a://qa/urls-final/")
```

Comment: the source object key should be `snapshots/urls/date=20220822.parquet` ; no leading / and no bucket url etc. Is that what you are passing in?

Answer (score 1):

For objects not accessed through an access point, specify the name of the source bucket and the key of the source object, separated by a slash (/). For example, to copy the object reports/january.pdf from the bucket **awsexamplebucket**, use **awsexamplebucket/reports/january.pdf.** The value must be URL-encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `/` to the start of your key.